# Best practice to prevent lack of tools?

Tags: banished

One of my biggest problem during a game of Banished is the ongoing lack of tools.
 Every citizen seems to need tools (of iron or steel) again and again.

What is the best practice to reduce the amount of such tools (made by the blacksmith)?

Comment: Are you asking about reducing the consumption of tools or how to make them efficiently?

Comment: Reducing the consumption of tools is my primary problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to reduce consumption of tools is to upgrade to steel tools, which last [twice as long as iron ones](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Tools).  Besides that, the only thing you can do to avoid a tool shortage is to

1. Increase the limit for the blacksmith if he/she is consistently hitting their limit
2. If not, make sure your blacksmith is productive by ensuring he/she doesn't have too far to walk
3. Build more blacksmiths
4. Always make sure you have enough iron and logs (and coal, if you go for the steel option).

Answer (score 5):

A tool crisis is a serious problem which can be the downfall of your village. Lack of tools greatly affects the productivity of almost all jobs, including blacksmiths, which in turn reduces the tool production even more and makes it hard to get out of. To make matters worse, a tool crisis will often be followed by a hunger-crisis and mass-starvation, because the productivity of all food-sources is also affected. Good luck increasing your tool production while your blacksmiths and builders are dying one after another.

That means a tool bottleneck needs to be prevented at all cost. Make sure that you always have at least one replacement tool stocked per adult citizen, better two. When your number of citizens exceeds the number of tools you have stocked, you need to act quickly and build more blacksmith workshops.

Also, make sure that your blacksmiths never run into a supply bottleneck. To prevent this from happening, get a forestry and a mine for a constant source of logs and iron. That way you no longer need to harvest iron and logs manually. When you have the manpower available, you should get a second mine to produce coal, so you can produce steel tools.

Answer (score 2):

Nicely said, would work probably, but in my case (having the same problems) i can not build up iron (mine or groundloot) fast enough, i got about 75 adults with 50 of them having no tool. So my food gathering drops fast because they don't have a tool. (I'm playing for the achievements "no Trader", "no Fields", "no Schools" on a large easy valley map, with therefor long walk routes for my citizens to get stuff (hence Tools, if i even got any). I got 2 blacksmiths (nr. 3 is in the making, but stopped building it for now). Even my blacksmiths have no tools atm. and since food drops i can not afford to lower citizens loot food either.
So a Tip: drop ALL you got going if you got a simular problem apart from the food gathering. 
That means even (yes truly)stone/coal/herbs/wood(assuming you DO have enough logs) production.
Only keep your Laborers loot iron from the ground, wood if needed, and keep iron mine(s) open.
To get enough people to do that, make all the next mentioned professional workers a Laborer until you got the tool problem solved (stone miners, coal miners, herbalists, woodcutters, tailors, brewers, clerics, etc) Do not drop a teacher, because students can help you also to solve the problem (make a new student builder f.e. because with builders you can make more Blacksmiths OR you can use the new build citizen student a replacement Blacksmith in your "old" Blacksmith building.

Comment: This is a long wall of text. Would you mind editing your answer so it is easier to read.